# Chrome javascript errors

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, browser

Google Chrome started to show errors in the console. The page is just a regular PHP page that has one function `echo 'a';`. I have attached a screenshot of the errors. [Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoHkW.jpg)

Comment: Show us full code please?

Comment: <?php echo 'a'; ?>

Comment: What is on the page when loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with some Chrome extensions, not with the page itself. Maybe update them, remove them or just ignore them.

Comment: Thank you guys. It was the Download accelerator extension. I disabled it, and that solved the problem.